# What is the MutableLiveData equivalent in RxJava?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

Per the example below from the LiveData Android documentation, what would be the RxJava 2 equivalent?

We certainly can use a combination of `publish()`, `refcount()` and `replay()` to achieve the core of the MutableLiveData observable behavior. That said, what would be the analogous counterpart of `mCurrentName.setValue()` as it pertains to detecting a change and emitting the corresponding event?

```
public class NameViewModel extends ViewModel {

// Create a LiveData with a String
private MutableLiveData<String> mCurrentName;

    public MutableLiveData<String> getCurrentName() {
        if (mCurrentName == null) {
            mCurrentName = new MutableLiveData<String>();
        }
        return mCurrentName;
    }

// Rest of the ViewModel...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could replicate the effects with `BehaviorSubject` on certain levels.

If you just want to notify observers:

```java
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

subject.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(1);
```

If you want to notify observers always on the main thread:

```java
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

Observable<Integer> observable = subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

observable.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(1);
```

If you want to be able to signal from any thread:

```java
Subject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

Observable<Integer> observable = subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

observable.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(1);
```

Use `createDefault` to have it with an initial value.

Comment: Is it ok to just use `create()` like this? This blog post makes it really scary on topic #2: https://medium.com/@jagsaund/5-not-so-obvious-things-about-rxjava-c388bd19efbc