# RxJava2 create() caution

Tags: rx-java2

Reading the topic #2 from [this article](https://medium.com/@jagsaund/5-not-so-obvious-things-about-rxjava-c388bd19efbc), it's clear that using `create()` properly can involve several issues, like:

- Unregister callbacks when an Observable is unsubscribed (failing to do so can cause memory leaks)
- Emit events using onNext or onCompleted only while a subscriber is still subscribed
- Propagate errors upstream using onError
- Handle backpressure

But seeing examples from the devs of RxJava2, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49720510/1227166), where `create()` is used without any further checks or warnings, makes me wonder how deep are the issues with `create()`?

If I want `Subject` that can push a value at anytime, just like the one in that link:

```
Subject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

Observable<Integer> observable = subject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

observable.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(1)
```

**Is it ok to use `create()` or is it dangerous as well? How to know when we need to protect `create()` emissions and when we don't have to?**

Comment: The aforementioned article is about 1.2.6, and in RxJava1 the `create` was renamed to `unsafeCreate`, and it is not even available in RxJava2 since its inception. The `Observable.create` in Rx2 is actually the `Observable.fromEmitter {` from Rx1, which was always safe to use.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking into the source code of `SingleFromCallable` and since it takes care of most of the things in the article I thought it was still valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` is not the same create as with `BehaviorSubject.create()`. The latter was always safe as it created a final and *pre-implemented* `BehaviorSubject`, which is a **hot** `Observable`.

`Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` was used to setup a **cold** `Observable` *from scratch* and required the developer to implement the whole observable protocol correctly. It was error prone and late in the 1.x, the `create(OnSubscribe)` method was deprecated. Please read its [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#create-rx.Observable.OnSubscribe-) for further details.

In RxJava 2, both types `create` methods are safe.